# Odoo 10 Consulta sql no devuelve valor

Tags: python, odoo

Tengo una consulta sencilla de sql pero no me devuelve ningún valor. ¿Dónde puede estar el error? Gracias

```
@api.model_cr
def _compute_impuestos(self):
    """ Event Question main report """
    tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'product.template')
    self._cr.execute(""" 
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            product_template
        LIMIT 1
    """)
    res = self._cr.fetchone()
    return res
```

Comment: ¿Puede añadir algo más? Por ejemplo, qué hay en la tabla `product_template`. ¿No será que has puesto un '.' en el nombre de la tabla?

Comment: Si cambio el  `product.template` por `product_template`  Odoo 10 me devuelve el siguente error:  ProgrammingError: "product_template" is not a view. En la tabla hay numeros (ids)

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que devuelve? Por "ningún valor" a qué te refieres concretamente.

Answer (score 0):

en el fragmento de código que muestras hay varias cosas que no entiendo para que las haces y puede ser lo que causa tu error.

```
tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'product.template')
```

Me parece que esto es innecesario porque esa vista no existe.

El decorador @api.model_cr para que lo usas?

Has hecho el debug del método?

Saludos